# MS Access Filter Form with DateTimePicker

Tags: ms-access

I need a little help.
I've created a textbox where i can set a date via DateTimePicker.
What i'd like to do is when i select 28.05.2016, the form should only display this date.

Can anyone help me out?

## Edit

i tried this onUpdate

```
DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "[Date] like '*" & DateSelector & "*'"
```

Comment: why `Like` instead of `=` ?

Comment: `Date` is a reserved word. Naming a field using a reserved word **IS** looking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use `AfterUpdate` event, the use

```
DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "[Date] = [forms].[myForm].[myControl]"
```

`Like` has little interest here since a partial entry of the date would trigger an error.

Alternatively you can use

```
DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "[Date] = " & Format([myControl], "\#mm/dd/yyyy\#")
```

Comment: My textbox where the date is selected is called DateSelect
And the field where the Dates should get filtered is called Date
`´DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "[Date ?? the name of my field?] = [forms].[??the name of my form?].[DateSelect]"´` is this wrong?

Comment: i changed the name of datefield datefilter i think its right what i need to change ^^

Comment: actually this isnt working `DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "[DateFilter] = [forms].[fmTagesangebote].[DateSelect]"`